# Kubernetes multi-container pod - number of instances per container

Tags: kubernetes

How can I specify the number of instances in container level (same pod) without duplicating code in my yaml file?
Example:

```
   spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-a
        image: image-a
      - name: app-b
        image: image-b
      - name: app-c-1
        image: image-c
      - name: app-c-2
        image: image-c
      - name: app-c-3
        image: image-c
```

You can see `app-c` is duplicated. How can I avoid that?

Comment: I think having such Pod is not a good idea. You could split your Pod into multiple Pods and change replicas in the Pod level. I don't think there is such ability to set replication count inside the pod. To me, it's meaningless.

Comment: @AliTou there are many reasons to use multi-container pods. My question is what if two or more use the same image.

Comment: If containers in a Pod do different jobs, they must have differences in other fields, e.g. args, right? So you're not actually duplicating anything when specifying their images. But if they're completely the same, it's when seems meaningless to have number of replicas or instances field in this level.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use a Deployment to specify this.  That includes a `replicas:` field that you can change dynamically.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: c
spec:
  replicas: 3 # <--
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: c
          image: image-c
```

You will also need a corresponding Service, which in turn requires adding appropriate labels to the pod template.

The approach you're describing actually won't work.  Say image-c listens on port 3000.  Since every container in a pod shares the same network namespace, all of the containers will try to listen on the pod's port 3000, but only one can succeed.

There are some standard reasons to prefer Deployments over Pods.  You can't change the replica count in your proposed setup without completely deleting and recreating the pod; and when you do this, you also will stop the unaffected containers `a` and `b`.  With a Deployment you can `kubectl scale deployment c --replicas=5` and it will start up two new pods without affecting anything else.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to do this with K8s manifests**.

I recommend you let the duplicated containers run in a separate *[Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)* or *[ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/)*.